# Is it possible to split windows without showing tabs in the middle?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

If I split the IDE into 2 sides, the tab list is duplicated. Is there any way to hide the one in the middle of the screen, to save space and make it easier to compare the 2 files?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. I can see a few possible options actually.

**1. Use more appropriate [Compare Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/comparing-files-and-folders.html) functionality:** look for `Compare with...` action in the context menu.

For example:

- Locate and select 2 files in the Project View, use context menu and choose `Compare Files` action.
- ... or select one file and use `Compare with...` -- now point to the 2nd file via file chooser dialog.
- ... or copy contents of one of the files into the Clipboard and then use `Compare with Clipboard...` in your Editor context menu (currently opened file).

NOTE: You can edit/merge files in Differences Viewer screen; when you exit it the changes will remain until auto-save or manual Save is called.

**2. Do not display list of the opened tabs on the right side:** put it at the top/bottom or temporarily hide it completely (until you are done with your comparing task).

You can change the tabs position quickly at any time via `Help | Find Action...` (or `Search Everywhere` via <kbd>Shift + Shift</kbd>) and search for `tab placement` -- it can then be changed right from there without the need to go into the Settings/Preferences screen (use the appropriate ON/OFF toggle).

[image]